# How to handle a Typeclass Instance requiring additional Type Constraints

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

I found myself in a situation where a typeclass instance I want to define requires additional type constraints. Specifically I want to define `Show` for a type `Trie a`:

```
data Trie a = Node {
    label :: a,
    edges :: DM.Map a (Trie a),
    isFinal :: Bool
}
```

while the instance for Show is:

```
import qualified Data.Tree as DT

instance (Show a, Eq a, Eq (Trie a)) => Show (Trie a) where
    show trie@(Node label edges _) = DT.drawTree (mapTree show $ toDataTree trie)
```

I required `Eq a` and `Eq (Trie a)` here, as I use `toDataTree` which converts a `Trie a` to a `DT.Tree a` and entails these type constraints:

```
import qualified Data.Map as DM

toDataTree :: (Eq a, Eq (Trie a)) => Trie a -> DT.Tree a
toDataTree (Node label edges isFinal)
    | edges == DM.empty = DT.Node label (map toDataTree (DM.elems edges))
    | otherwise = DT.Node label []

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> DT.Tree a -> DT.Tree b
mapTree f (DT.Node rootLabel subForest) = DT.Node (f rootLabel) $ map (mapTree f) subForest
```

Now while this does compile, when I actually want to call `print` on a `Trie a` (where `a` = `Char` in this case) I get

```
• No instance for (Eq (Trie Char)) arising from a use of ‘print’
• In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

This must be because I needed to add these additional type constraints to the instance of `Show`. So my approach is probably wrong.

What is the correct solution for additional type constraints being required for a type class instance definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume there's a bug in your program in the `toDataTree` guard and you meant:

```
| edges /= DM.empty = ...
```

However, you don't need `Eq` instances to check that a map is empty.  If you use `DM.null` instead, you can drop the `Eq` constraints from `toDataTree` and from the `Show` instance:

```
toDataTree :: Trie a -> DT.Tree a
toDataTree (Node label edges isFinal)
    | not (DM.null edges) = DT.Node label 
                             (map toDataTree (DM.elems edges))
    | otherwise = DT.Node label []
```

In fact, if the map is empty, then mapping over its elements will produce an empty list anyway, so you can further simplify this to:

```
toDataTree :: Trie a -> DT.Tree a
toDataTree (Node label edges isFinal)
  = DT.Node label (map toDataTree (DM.elems edges))
```

Anyway, that should solve your immediate problem.

Setting all that aside, the reason for the error is that you haven't provided any `Eq` instance for any `Trie`.  You could add a `deriving (Eq)` clause to the definition for `Trie`:

```
data Trie a = Node {
    label :: a,
    edges :: DM.Map a (Trie a),
    isFinal :: Bool
} deriving (Eq)
```

This might give you a scary warning about fragile inner bindings, but you can drop the `Eq (Trie a)` constraints (because they will be implied by the `Eq a` constraint) from both the `Show` instance and `toDataTree` to make the warning go away.

Still, as mentioned, you don't really want to do this, because using `DM.null` and bypassing the `Eq` instances entirely is better practice.

Comment: Thanks.  Just a copy and paste error working through too many versions. It's fixed now.